# How to Solve the inner Exception i.e. index out of range

Tags: c#, winforms

I am storing items into a combo box which had been retrieved from the database in the following manner:

```
cmbCustomerName.DataSource = null;
cmbCustomerName.DataSource = result;
cmbCustomerName.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
cmbCustomerName.DisplayMember = "CustomerName";
cmbCustomerName.Text = null;
```

Its working, but often showing the inner exception "Index Out of Range". Why does this error occur?

Comment: Which line corresponds to the exception being thrown?

Comment: Any reason you are setting the `DataSource` to `null` and to `result` in the first two consecutive lines?

Comment: yes,For Clearing the DataSource I have Used "Null",that result is a datatable name

Comment: You'll need to post the StackTrace of the inner exception.

Comment: The following is my StackTrace of the inner exception.

              System.IndexOutOfRangeException was caught
                 Message="Index 3 does not have a value."
               Source="System.Windows.Forms"
           StackTrace:
        at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.get_SelectedValue()
       at Bill.OrderDetails.cmbCompanys_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Narmadha\Godwins 1.1.1.22(final)(MyChanges)\Godwins\Godwins\OrderDetails.cs:line 1585
  InnerException:

Answer (score 1):

You have given us next to no code, can you be sure that the exception is happening in that bit of code you posted?

I'm assuming that you are wanting to have the combo unselected after you set its `DataSource` which is why you are setting the `Text` to null, if i am wrong then please say so.

To unselect everything in the combo, set the `SelectedIndex` to -1. There is also no need to set the `DataSource` to null before setting it to something else.

Comment: I tried the method what you have told ,But then also that exception is coming some times

Comment: We need to know *where* the exception is happening - what line? What are the surrounding lines of code? This should all be easy to determine if you are using a debugger.